# How to prevent corrupted files?

Tags: android, video, mediarecorder

I am making and recording application. And the big problem for me is that when user click the record button( i am using custom recorder, not default intent) and if they hit it again quickly or MediaRecorder is going to throw exception or video file will be corrupted. I tried to setEnabled() on buttons but that doesn't seems to work...i don't know why, it seems like they are not disabled for some reason...

Can somebody please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't hurt to have more than one layer of validation.  In addition to setEnabled(false) on your record button, try adding some logic to prevent a dirty write.  Code assumes you're operating on a single thread.

```
boolean inProgress;

onClick()
{
    inProgress = true;
    record();
}

public boolean record()
{
    if(!inProgress)
    {
        // record sound
        // don't forget to reset inProgress if record success/fail
    }
}
```